# get copied content inside onCopy hook (plugin)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, slatejs, react-slate

I am trying to get copied fragment into `onCopy` hook vainly.

I've been trying with the `event.clipboardData...`

```js
const { clipboardData } = event;
const encoded = clipboardData.getData("application/x-slate-fragment");
```

But it seems as empty. I have also tried with the `getEventTransfer` utils. But it returns `{type: 'unknow'}`

Here is the [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-slate-forked-yxvcn?file=/src/index.js:1228-1343) that I have been testing.

Answer (score 1):

i think its not possible with the `saltejs` to get the fragment, if your will see the doucmentation as well https://docs.slatejs.org/v/v0.47/slate-react/utils#functions here as well they are asking to make the fragment first and then copy the data to it. So i think you could use JavaScript for it, if it helps, just a suggestion.

if you just want to get the copied text then try plain javascript inside `onCopy` function

`const copied_text = window.getSelection().toString();`

if your want to get the  fragment of copied text use

`event.target.outerHTML` or `event.target.innerHTML`  in `onCopy function`

if you want to create another copied fragment you can do

`document.createRange().createContextualFragment(event.target.outerHTML)`

Comment: I appreciate your answer, however I would like to find a way to do it with the original slate copied objects (not just the text). In addittion InnertHTML and outerHTML contain the whole element, even copying a piece of the element

Comment: What I need is to get fragment object to inyect it new data, and then get that data in onPaste hook... :/

Comment: I haven't gotten the copied fragment yet... You have answered me to get the text, but it is not exactly what I asked